# Passing a parameter from a listview to crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, crystal-reports

I am new at creating a crystal report for web application. I'm trying to pass a parameter from a listview item to a crystal report

I'm using this to pass the parameter

```
<a href='../Reports/UserDetails.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("UserID") %>'><i class= "fa fa-print"></i>
```

This is the code I use for behind the aspx that calls the crystal report

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
        {
            int userID = 0;
            bool validUser = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString(), out userID);

            if (validUser)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {

                    GetInfo(userID);

                }
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
void GetInfo(int ID)
{

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Users.UserID, Types.UserType, Users.Email, Users.LastName, " +
        "Users.FirstName, Users.ContactNumber, Branch.BranchName, Users.Status, Users.DateAdded, " +
        "Users.DateModified FROM Users " +
        "INNER JOIN Types ON Users.TypeID = Types.TypeID " +
        "INNER JOIN Branch ON Users.BranchID = Branch.BranchID WHERE UserID=@UserID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Users");
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Reports/rptUserDetails.rpt"));
    //report.SetParameterValue("@UserID", ID);
    //report.SetParameterValue("@UserID", ID);
    crvUsers.ReportSource = report;
    crvUsers.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdxDX.jpg)

I debug the program it keeps on asking the parameter I am trying to send. It must not anymore ask for the value

Comment: You've got your set parameter value commented out, presumably it doesn't work when that's uncommented? Could you post your record selection formula from your report and a screenshot of the parameters configured in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncomment the parameter line `report.SetParameterValue("@UserID", ID);`
if it not work remove the @ symbol from UserID parameter and also set the same name parameter in crystal report.